# Nativescript - what are the limitations

Tags: cordova, nativescript

I am considering switching from Cordova to Nativescript for my next mobile app project.  I have looked at what NativeScript offers and find much of it to my liking.  However, I have a few questions

- Does using NativeScript in the cloud entail any limitations on what can/cannot be done?  I ask the question since PhoneGap Build (which i do not use) does impose several constraints
- NativeScript has plugins for things like Geolocation, Accelerometry, Bluetooth and WebSockets.  In general in Cordova I have eschewed the plugin approach and simply relied on one plugin I maintain myself since cross-plugin communications in Cordova results in very messy code.  Is this a constraint with NS plugins too or can I rely on being able to work seamlessly with the pugins out of NS given that the end result is a true compiled native app rather than a hybrid
- Finally, are there any other limitations with using NativeScript, particuarly on the front of accessing other device hardware or rather more exotic device APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, Cordova & NativeScript can not be compared as they are entirely different.

You may able to reuse the same HTML / CSS and even most of JavaScript from Web app while building your Cordova based hybrid app.

But with NativeScript, you may able to reuse your business logic and the UI has to be completely rewritten as it builds a complete native app here. It's seen as an advantage over Cordova unless you don't really prefer native ux for your app.

But when it comes to limitations, I would say {N} has zero limitations if you learn the core concepts of the framework. It gives you 100% device API access from JavaScript. You don't have to know Objective C / Java or Kotlin but still access all APIs instantly. If you are familiar with TypeScript, life is even more easier with [tns-platform-declarations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations) which gives intellisense support for all device APIs.

As everything is JavaScript for the most part, often it's easy to override the prototype chain to customize any built-in component or plugins.

But honestly, the community is comparatively smaller so you may not find all the plugins but only most essentials. You may check [Marketplace](https://market.nativescript.org/) for all available plugins. If you are a good learner, you always have decent support from other developers / experts in platform within Slack / SO.

Comment: Thanks.  Just one other question - in Cordova I implemented my own plugin to handle access to geolocation, websockets, accelrometry etc since it is at best clumsy to get a disparate set of plugins to "talk" to each other.  I am not even sure that I will use external plugins in {N} but would like to know nevertheless - given that JS is used purely as a convenient high level language with the output being true native code is it less of an issue in in {N} - i.e is it easier to get the plugins to work together seamlessly?

Comment: Plugins can talk to each other easily here, there are a few plugins already built on top of another. And Yes you will have to often use external plugins, the framework covers only most essential components. Not all the apps do need geo location / web sockets but all do need layouts / text inputs / buttons / fetch APIs etc., those which comes out of the box. I hope that answers your question.